# mongodb WARNING: You are running on a NUMA machine

Tags: 16.04, mongodb

I have a dedicated server running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I have a problem with mongoDB service. When I enter in the shell I receive this message :

```
WARNING: You are running on a NUMA machine.
We suggest launching mongod like this to avoid performance problems:
numactl --interleave=all mongod [other options]
```

How can I solve it?
I already have tried a solution like : [How should I start MongoDB on a NUMA machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293468/how-should-i-start-mongodb-on-a-numa-machine)
and : http://greproot.com/warning-you-are-running-on-a-numa-machine-we-suggest-launching-mongod-like-this-to-avoid-performance-problems-numactl-interleaveall-mongod-other-options/
but nothing...
sorry for bad English :D

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/293468/how-should-i-start-mongodb-on-a-numa-machine and more specific this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/622853/15811

Comment: when i type "sudo restart mongod" i recive this error :" Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused"

Comment: hmmm 16.04 uses systemd not upstart ;) Probably need to change it to `systemctl start mongodb.service`

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Jacek - If using a dedicated server for mongodb disabling NUMA in BIOS is a good option. For production scenarios, it has been suggested to use the **numactl** command to future-proof for NUMA awareness.

To make mongod start using interleaved mode, add `numactl –interleave=all` before your regular `mongod` command:

```
numactl --interleave=all mongod < mongod options>
```

If using numaclt method, also disable vm zone reclaim zone_reclaim_mode to 0 by adding: `vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 0` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`, save it and execute `sysctl -p` to load the new settings into the kernel.

For more insights - https://engineering.linkedin.com/performance/optimizing-linux-memory-management-low-latency-high-throughput-databases

Answer (score 1):

You may disable NUMA as mentioned in the message you copy/pasted for the process.
You may also disable it system wide in grub, setting numa=off for the kernel.
Another option is disabling it in BIOS - may depend on hardware you use (for Dell, for example, it would be setting "Node Interleaving" to "Enable")
That would be a good solution if you have a dedicated database server for Mongo.

You can verify it later using "numactl -H" command - you should see only one node presented.

Generally - you may also - depending on your exact situation, just ignore the message if your mongo instance isn't too big.
It may not be really a critical problem, but Mongo during startup warns you about your settings, which may cause issues.
Yes - on production system, with a lot of data, big memory allocations - you may suffer from performance issues or even have memory allocation failures.